# IE11 garbled character on all js file

Tags: angular, internet-explorer-11

I tried adding meta charset in the html header and charset in script tag, both didn't work.
I'm baffled.
btw system language is Chinese, if thats relevent, I tried switching language to english, didn't help.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the answer.
Even though I set charset=utf-8 in my Content-Type.
My CDN provider rewrited my header and deleted that line.

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution for this issue. I suggest you to try to mark your own answer as an accepted answer for this question after 48 hrs, when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.